# How to stop aria2 from renaming HTML files?

Tags: aria2

I am using [aria2](https://aria2.github.io) and [uGet](https://ugetdm.com) (which is a GUI for aria2) to download files, however it renames the HTML files, for example I download this link https://www.wowhead.com/item=10001 and it saves the file renamed as "black-mageweave-robe" (without extension).

I need the downloaded file to have a name like "item=10001" (without extension), just like the name you get when using wget

I am using Windows, but I guess they act the same on Linux too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*aria2* does not rename the files, *wget* does - more about that later. *aria2* does not have a way to automatically behave like *wget* on every download, but you can get the name you want by creating a download list with options (note the mandatory whitespace before the option):

```
https://www.wowhead.com/item=10001
 out=item=10001
https://www.wowhead.com/item=10002
 out=item=10002
```

Then use the file as an input:

```
aria2c -i files.txt
```

If you are using *aria2* you probably have a lot of files to download and is already generating a list of files using some sort of script, so this should not be that difficult. A clever text editor could also do this with a good search-and-replace operation.

##### Why *wget* lies to you

When you try to download `item=10001` the server informs you that there is no such path on the server. However, it helpfully tells us:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /item=10001/black-mageweave-robe
```

A plain browser will follow the redirect and - according to the HTTP standard - will update the URI to match. *wget* *does* retry the new location but pretends the redirect never happens and uses the old name. I personally think this is a flaw in wget, which just so happened to meet your requirements in this case!

You can have *wget* use the new location with the `--trust-server-names` flag.

Comment: The possibility to specify options in the input file is absolutely great! Does aria2 have an option to use the old name, like the default wget setting? I do not quite agree that the wget behaviour is a flaw, it is not a browser, it is a download utility so if you specify an url in a certain way - an url that redirects, you probably do it for a good reason: because you want certain output filenames. However, would be nice if aria2 would have this feature - or flaw, whatever you want to call it.

Comment: @JoeJobs Yes, what "correct" means is is definitely debatable. I have never found a way to configure aria2 in this way though, although I vaguely remember having had the same "issue" as you.